# Is it correct to use enum in this case?

Tags: java, enums

This is a question about best practice/style.

I have a Printer class that can print out an element with different colors. Is it correct to use an Enum as input like this:

```
public class Printer {

public enum Color{RED, GREEN, BLUE}

public void print (Color color){
    MyElement myElement = new MyElement();
    switch (color) {
        case RED:
            myElement.setColor("#xxxxxx");
            break;
        case GREEN:
            myElement.setColor("#xxxxxx");
            break;
        case BLUE:
            myElement.setColor("#xxxxxx");
            break;
    }
    myElement.print();
}

}
```

And then just call the method from another class like this:

```
Printer p = new Printer();
p.print(Printer.Color.RED);
```

... or would it be better to add the values to enum like this:

```
public class Printer {

    public enum Color {
        RED("#xxxxxx"), 
        GREEN("#xxxxxx"), 
        BLUE("#xxxxxx");

        private final String hex;

        Color(String hex){
            this.hex = hex;
        }

        public String getHex(){
            return this.hex;
        }
    }

    public void print (Color color){
        MyElement myElement = new MyElement();
        myElement.setColor(color.getHex());
        myElement.print();
    }

}
```

... or maybe not use enum at all and just use plain string?

Comment: Enum sounds good, but you should definitely include the RGB value into the Enum. Or just define an Interface with a bunch of constants. Or use one that's already there, like `java.awt.Color.CYAN.getRGB()`

Comment: Object oriented would be to place the hex representation in the enum, as it is clearly intrinsic to Color. A switch is less strict.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (but I can't seem to flag it for migration there...), here it might be closed as opinion-based

Comment: I would rather suggest to have Color Enum in a separate class file. This makes your Code Coverage cleaner. Further , the second implementation looks better since it contains the attributes to the color. If you have sep. file for Enum - when writing JUNIT test case for Printers - u dont have to write JUNIT Test cases for Color.

Comment: Enums can hold extra information, but in this case being colors I won't hardcode color tones inside them, because those are usually susceptible of modification. But I don't know how your project works so it might be fine for you.

Comment: I'd even say there should not be any enum or hash of colors inside the Printer. Pass the hex code as param much more modifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your solution. The only thing I would would suggest is to create a constructor on the Enum and store the color value over there. But it's just a suggestion.

It would be like this:

```
public class Printer {

public enum Color{
    RED("#FF0000"), GREEN("#00FF00"), BLUE("#0000FF");

    private String colorAsString;

    private Color(String colorAsString) {
        this.colorAsString = colorAsString;
    }

    public String getColorAsString() {
        return this.colorAsString;
    }
}

public void print (Color color){
    MyElement myElement = new MyElement();
    myElement.setColor(color.getColorAsString());
    myElement.print();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Using an `enum` in the place of constants usually makes sense. If the application is as simple as explained in the question, with only 1 parameter (the color value), using string constants is also efficient.

If an `enum` is to be used, the second approach (i.e., the one storing the color value via the `enum` constructor) is preferable.